# Pushing all product and product change data from Spree to a remote API

Tags: spree

I have a unique requirement, for which I couldn't find anything on the documentation. (or I may have missed it).

I am building an extension to provide custom search implementation for Spree Commerce, and I am done with the extension.

The problem is getting the data from spree. I need all the products and I need products which are modified to be sent to the remote API.

I could write an tool to get the data using the API's/Webhooks, but is there a way by which I can push these from the spree extension itself? Also pulling entire product inventory every time does't look like a good solution. Can someone please guide me here.